# CakePHP: $this->Session->setFlash only works if redirect is configured

Tags: php, redirect, cakephp

I have a function that assigns a document a number if two required fields are filled in. Here is the Controller code:

```
if( ($data['Msr']['app_requester_id'] == 0 && isset($data['Msr']['app_requester_date']) ||
      (empty($data['Msr']['app_requester_date'] && $data['Msr']['app_requester_id'] > 0 )) )) {

      $this->Session->setFlash(__('You must sign and date this document before a number can be assigned.'));
      $this->redirect(array('action'=>'edit', $id));
    }
```

This works fine as long as $this->redirect is present. Thing is, I don't want to redirect the user, because then they'll lose any unsaved changes if this error condition is encountered. But if I remove $this->redirect, it doesn't work, and the number gets assigned even if one or both of the required fields are blank. Is there a way to get this to work without a redirect?

Comment: Also: Always return your redirect. You forgot that here.

Comment: @mark Why adding `return` for `redirect` if by defaults it exuctes an `exit(0)` at the end ! Am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try validating the data before you save and throwing an [Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) if the required fields are blank.

```
try {
    if (($data['Msr']['app_requester_id'] == 0 && isset($data['Msr']['app_requester_date'])
        || (empty($data['Msr']['app_requester_date'] && $data['Msr']['app_requester_id'] > 0 )))
    ) {
        throw new Exception('Exception message');
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->data = array(
        'success' => false,
        'message' => $e->getMessage()
    );
}
```

Comment: Same result, unfortunately. The conditions are bypassed completely. Odd, because I see where this *should* work.